# Can anyone please explain what does mapreduce.job.reduces =-1 means

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

Need to understand the purpose of mapreduce.job.reduces = -1. I understand the attribute mapreduce.job.reduces reduces the file output to the configured value, but what does -1 means.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Hive's documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties):

> mapred.reduce.tasks  <-- (In YARN it is mapreduce.job.reduces)
>  
>       Default Value: -1 
>       Added In: Hive 0.1.0
>
> The default number of reduce tasks per job. Typically set to a prime close to the number of available hosts. Ignored when mapred.job.tracker is "local". Hadoop set this to 1 by default, whereas Hive uses -1 as its default value. By setting this property to -1, Hive will automatically figure out what should be the number of reducers.

Setting the number of reducers is much more than setting the number of output files. It somehow defines the level of parallelism, i.e., how many reduce tasks will run in parallel. If using 1 reduce task, no parallelism is achieved. If 2 reduce tasks are used, *ideally*, you want to cut the workload (and execution time) of each reduce task to half. The same holds for the number of mappers, but this is trickier to set.